# Corrupted El Capitan installer?

Tags: macos

I've got a problem that while installing El Capitan from USB Installer it says "copy of software is corrupted etc..etc". Actually I downloaded the copy of El Capitan from another Mac and then I created "El Capitan installer from my own Mac with terminal process and when I try to install it it says the above message  "copy of software is corrupted etc..etc". So tell me please anyone what happened and if it's date fault, then what date I should set because I didn't download El Capitan on the Mac on which I want to install it.

Please can anyone help me to sort out this problem??

Comment: It sounds like the installer may not have been copied over correctly.  Can you create the USB installer on the Mac where you downloaded it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

Go to System Preferences and manually change the date to January 1st 2016. More specifically, deselect *Set date and time automatically* and then manually enter the date and click Save.

After doing this, double click on the El Capitan installer and follow the prompts to install the software.

If you run into problems, a couple of additional things you can try are:

1. Disconnect from the internet before manually changing the date and stay disconnected until you've done the installation
2. Copy the installer onto the hard drive rather than running it from the USB

Let me know how you go.

Comment: I'm really thankfull to your work and I appreciate you're giving me your precious time. Its gonna work 100% fine. I doesn't have words to give you respect thanks sir and hats off to you.

Comment: Could you please explain why change the date works? What problem does it solve?

Comment: At the risk of oversimplifying things, one of the checks the system does to determine the validity of the installer is the date. If you're using a copy that was downloaded quite some time in the past, it'll fail. As the OP said they had downloaded the installer from another Mac, I figured that was the case here. Also, as the OP asked the question after macOS Sierra was released, El Capitan was not the latest OS, hence also increasing the likelihood the date was a problem. I picked 1 January 2016 as that was only 3 months since El Capitan was released and a date most likely to pass the check.

Comment: did works Same error

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to to confirm that @Monomeeth is absolutely right. I tried what he said and it worked! Than you!!

Steps:

1. Boot into USB with the macOS on it.
2. Disconnect from Wi-Fi if connected. Just turn it off for now..
3. Click Utilities tab, then Open Terminal.
4. Type `date 0101121216` (which sets date to Jan 1st 2016 12:12 PM)
5. Type `cd /Volumes/Image` and **do not press <kbd>Return</kbd> yet**, Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead, then press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
6. Type `cd Inst`, and again, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd>.
7. Type `cd Contents/MacOS/` and press <kbd>Return</kbd> this time.
8. Type `./Ins` press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd> and the installer should pop up and go from there to install the OS.

Comment: didn't works.. Same error :(

Comment: You can also just launch the insaller from the GUI as well. Many old macs also have a dead PRAM battery so they will have a clock set impossibly early for the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Someone may find this topic one day, so here it is how it worked for me after reading 20 threads like this one. Enough said I tried long list of things until this finally worked, and I swear I did similar things multiple times before that didn't worked.

1. I've downloaded the .dmg of El Capitan from a link on the iclarified.com site on my Mac running X Lion 10.7.
2. Noticed the creation date of the InstallPackage was 24 Oct 2019, 9:08 am
3. Disabled Wifi.
4. Disabled Automatic time update.
5. Set the Date to be 24 Oct 2019, 10:10.
6. Installed the Package that created the Install Application.
7. Opened the Application, it did load the complete bar without getting the "Tampered or Corruped" error.
8. Mac restarted and now is installing the OS...

I'd say the key is to know exactly what is the creation date of the Installer in order to set the same date on the machine. Don't know if the creation date is different from the date you downloaded the update, but they seem different so get the "Creation" one.